# How can I run PHP script using a HTML Form without redirecting to a new page?

Tags: php

I have a simple html form that looks like the following

```
  <form action="search.php" method="get">
    <p>Company Name:
       <input type="text" name="name" />
    </p>    
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value = "Search"/>
    </p>
  </form>
```

Simple enough, however the problem is I am redirected to `search.php` (which resides in the same directory as this form page). I would like to be able to display the search results on the same page, (below the form) without redirecting to `search.php`. What do you suggest?

Comment: Or refresh your current page and look for a POST and then setup your page that way.

Comment: Javascript is not permitted as this is not intended for use by web browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the form to redirect on the same page

```
<form action="yourPage.php" method="post">
<p>Company Name:
   <input type="text" name="name" />
</p>    
<p>
  <input type="submit" value = "Search"/>
</p>
```

And then check in this php page if the form has been filled or not

```
    if(isset($_POST['a_field_of_your form']){
//treat the values of the form
}
```

And then display the result after the form in the page!

This method inply that the page will be reloaded, if you don't want it to happen you'll have to use Ajax to submit the form and get the search result from the Ajax request!

Comment: And your not reliant on JavaScript like the other answers suggest.  Although doing both is the way to go.

Comment: The best way would be both: the Ajax way if javascript is allowed by the browser and Post to the same page if Javascript is not!

Comment: But he has mentioned "without redirecting to search.php"

Comment: Yeah, i didn't understand if he meant that he doesn't want the page to be reloaded" (so the solution would be ajax) or if doesn't want the visitors to go on an other page (and he doesn't care of the page being refreshed) and in this case implementing the form validation and handlng in the same page is a valid solution!

Comment: agreed it was not clear. +1 for you:)

Comment: Thank your for this response. I did exactly that, simply adding     `if(isset($_POST['a_field_of_your form'])
 require "search.php";`

Answer (score 4):

Use [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com)

Then you can invoke *ajax* (client-server request from javascript) easily (See [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) )

For example, if you have a search form with id **search-form** and container with id **search-results** to show search results, then you can:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit_search() {

    var request_data = $('#search-form').serailize();
    $.post('search.php', request_data, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $('#search-results').html(data);
        }, 'html');
    }
</script>

<form id="search-form" action="search.php" method="post" onsubmit="submit_searh();return false;">
<input type="text" name="q">
<input type="submit" value="Search!">
</form>

<div id="search-results"></div>
```

Comment: This probably should've [been a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @nickb you're right, sorry. added usage exmaple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library to submit the form through ajax

[Ajax Submit](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

Example:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

    <script> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            // bind 'myForm' (is an id of form) and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function(response) { 
                  //handle search results
                alert("Thank you for your search!"); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using AJAX.  Use javascript (or whatever library you are using for javascript) and send an AJAX request to search.php with the values from the form.  You'll need to gather those for yourself.  You'll also need to make search.php return something you can insert into the page and not a whole page itself.